# LESS not loading with Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, webpack

I was using Gulp but now trying to run my site via webpack v4.  Bear with me I'm new to webpack.

**TopNav.js** - React component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    export default class TopNav extends Component{
      render(){
        return (
          <nav className="ink-navigation bottom-border-grey-veryLight">
            <div className="column-group">
              <div className="all-45">
                <ul className="ft-topnav menu horizontal">
                  <li>
                    <Link className="margin-top-10" ref="link" to={"/"}>
                      <span className="underline-grey large underlined">
                        <span className="font-black">H</span><span className="grey-dark">ome</span>
...
```

the problem is now, the **grey-dark** and other styles I setup in my **master.less** are not working.

Prior to this, **gulp** processed my less files like so:

```
function precompile(cb) {
  src('./src/client/less/*.less')
    .pipe(
      less({
        compress: true,
      })
    )
    .pipe(hash())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/client/css'))
    .pipe(hash.manifest('styles-manifest.json'))
    .pipe(dest('.'));
  cb();
}
```

so it would output a **.css** file for **master.less**

now I'm using a **webpack.config.js** file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
          },
          {
            loader: 'less-loader', // compiles Less to CSS
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { injectType: 'linkTag' } },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['url-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './src/client/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
      hash: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```

In **index.html**, it's trying to use **master.css** as it always had:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/css/ink.min.css">
        <script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/autoload.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ink-ie.min.css" type="text/css">
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/css/master.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="/scripts/app.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not sure what I'm missing here.

**Error screenshot**

Got the errors:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `less-loader` to work, it should be in the dependency tree which starts with your `entry: './src/client/index.js',` js file, since you are not importing it, it won't be in the dependency graph.

If you have one `less` file add an import in your entry file to it.
If you have `less` file for each component, add import in the component js file.

```js
// TopNav.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'TopNav.less'; // <- add this

    export default class TopNav extends Component{
    ...
```